# How to implement a new policy in Razor Pages with addAuthorization?

Tags: c#, .net, authorization, asp.net-authorization

Objective:
Once logged in, be authorized to reroute to Contact page which is authorized with the
Must Belong To HR Department policy.
(Note: Using razor pages)

Expected:
Log in, see the claims in user for HR department, have the policy requirements be read, allow the user access to the contact page.

Actual:
Log in successfully, see claims in user for HR department, policy requirements not read or met or something, denied the user access to the contact page.

Program.cs file:

```
//Authorization
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{

    options.AddPolicy("MustBelongToHRDepartment",
            policy => policy.RequireClaim("Department", "HR"));


});

////RazorPage Options
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
 
    options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/contact", "MustBelongToHRDepartment");

});
```

Login page:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(User user)
        {


            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.username,
                           user.password, user.rememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {

                _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");

                    //Create the security context
                    var claims = new List<Claim> {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "admin"),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "admin@mywebsite.com"),
                    new Claim("Department", "HR")
                    };

                    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "MyCookieAuth");
                    ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

                    await HttpContext.SignInAsync("MyCookieAuth", claimsPrincipal);

                    return RedirectToPage("contact");
                }
                else
                {
                    return Page();
                }
        }
```

Is there anything I'm missing? Format? Silly error?

I have tried docs, YouTube videos, website, asking friends, and searching forums.

I have tried different methods of authorization and such, but nothing seems to work.
This method I am using now should work according to documentation, but I know something is wrong with it.

Resources I have been using:
[This is a YouTube video on register and login](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sogS0DtejVA)
[docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/razor-pages-authorization?view=aspnetcore-7.0)
[docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: The authorization on the page is implemented, the user is getting the claim, but the policy is not being implemented or read or something

Comment: Damn, 3 days. I thought I structured the question well.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var IdeUser = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(user.username);
                await _userManager.AddClaimsAsync(IdeUser, claims);
                var claimsPrincipal = await _signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(IdeUser);
                await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(IdeUser);
```

I added this and it worked. I think claims weren't going to userManager.

Comment: claims is a list of claims